# Rich pick list tab order

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using rich:picklist. It has to two list boxes as it has and four buttons in between for moving one or all . I need to give tab order to this picklist together with buttons and boxes.
Can anyone  help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't beacause there isn't [tab index on the component](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/pickList.jsf?tab=info&cid=775374).

Looking on the generated html source, boxes are tables and buttons are div : hard to define a tab order without the generated ids on such components...

Comment: i know....thts the challange, we tried giving ids to component,tab order works,but events are left unbinded and functionality disturbs.